# "TypeError: Network request failed" (React Native) Android fetch fails to work with local backend

Tags: android, spring-boot, react-native, axios, fetch

I am trying to fetch from my react native app using my local backend, and it keeps failing. The fetch doesn't even hit my backend, I made debug messages and tested on my browser to make sure the rest api worked. It works on iOS. I am also able to access other websites, so the internet works on the emulator.

**UPDATE:** After further debugging and trying other fetch requests, I have found a different error, maybe they are related?

```
error Could not open fetch.umd.js in the editor.
info When running on Windows, file names are checked against a whitelist to protect against remote code execution attacks. File names may consist only of alphanumeric characters (all languages), periods, dashes, slashes, and underscores.
```

I've already added `"android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in my AndroidManifest.xml. I have also tried upgrading my react native to **version 63.4** but the problem persists.

It prints to console "[GET] [http://127.0.0.1:8090/api/v1/user/check/email/test@gmail.com"](http://127.0.0.1:8090/api/v1/user/check/email/test@gmail.com%22) but then the app gets

> "TypeError: Network request failed"

immediately after.

When I try that URL in my browser, it properly prints
`{"transok":"0","errno":"001003","errmsg":"","timestamp":"1612157175224","data":{}}`

I've spent days in frustration on this, if anyone could lead me in the right direction I would be unimaginably greatful. Please let me know if any more information is needed, I will edit this question to provide the details

This is the code for the fetch  which doesnt work:

```
const APP_SERVER_HOST = 'http://127.0.0.1:8090';
const API_BASE = APP_SERVER_HOST + '/api';
const API_VERSION = '/v1';
const API_HOST = API_BASE + API_VERSION;

  isEmailExist(callback) {
    var url = API_HOST + '/user/check/email/'+this.state.email;
    var options = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    };
    console.log('[GET] ' + url);
//url is http://127.0.0.1:8090/api/v1/user/check/email/test@gmail.com
//url should post {"transok":"0","errno":"001003","errmsg":"","timestamp":"1612157175224","data":{}}
    fetch(url, options).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        var retCode = responseData.errno;
        console.log('[RTN] ' + responseData);
        console.log('[RTN] ' + JSON.stringify(responseData));
        if(retCode == Env.dic.ERROR_EMAIL_NOT_REG) {
          console.log('[RTN] error email not reg');
          return callback(false);
        } else if(retCode == Env.dic.ERROR_EMAIL_EXIST){
          console.log('[RTN] error email exist');
          return callback(true);
        }
      }).done();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` represents the emulator's localhost address. If you want to hit your machine's localhost you'll have to replace it with `10.0.2.2`.

See Android [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking) for more information on why this is the case.

Comment: This fixed it, it also works with my IPv4 address. Thanks so much :)